# Why old release apk delete after new apk created in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, build, release

When I create a new sign apk file, the old renamed apk file is deleted in Android Studio.

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 2):

I've also noticed this behavior recently.  I change the APK file name with each build, and it used to leave the old APK's.  Now whenever I create an APK Android Studio deletes all of the old APK's.

I'm using Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.